# Iterate over an array using async js and executing a function inside callback to return a single result

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I'm running a Node Js server and I'm receiving the following content from my frontend:

```
{
  dataType: "any",
  fechaI: "any",
  fechaF: "any",
  checkedList: [ "any obj","any obj"]
}
```

I have to iterate over the `checkedList` array in order to get the `action` property of all of its objects and then make use of the import for queries

```
const query = require("./queries.js")

query[item.action](req,res,resp,function(err,data){
            console.log(data)
        })
```

I want to set a variable with all the results of the query after the iteration is complete, I have tried using async.each but the queries return undefined objects. Also all the other properties of the content I get aren't passed to the query item properly.

Here's what I have tried so far:

```
    async.each(checkedList ,function(item, next) {
       let results =[]
 
        query[item.action](req, res, resp, function(err, data) {
            console.log(data)
            results.push(data)
            console.log(results)
            next()
        }.bind({results:results}))
    }, function(err) {
        if (err) console.log(err)
        console.log('done')
    })
```

The output of console.log(data) is undefined however results does return a value but it belongs to the last item of the array. What am I doing wrong in this scenario?

Comment: Might as well use a regular loop since you want a result after all of those async executions. Otherwise, create a bunch of Promises and use `Promise.all()`.

Comment: so i would have to make the query a promise and then i should map the results to the array?

Comment: Oh, I see you want to do `query`s. Keeping the `async` loop makes sense. Wrap the `query` in a Promise that is `resolve`d after your `results.push(data)`. Then pass all those Promises into `Promise.all()`.

Comment: Could you answer how would that look? It would be very helpful

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing your code I think, but am not sure, you want to do something like:

```js
function whatever(){
  const listData = [];
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    async.each(checkedList, (item, next)=>{
      query[item.action](req, res, resp, (err, data)=>{
        listData.push(data);
        if(listData.length === checkedList.length)resolve(listData);
        next();
      });
    }, err=>{
      console.log(err); reject(err);
    });
  });
}
whatever().then(listRes=>{
  console.log(listRes);
});
```

Personally, I would just call a function when you have all your results instead of returning something:

```js
function whatever(doneFunc){
  const listData = [];
  async.each(checkedList, (item, next)=>{
    query[item.action](req, res, resp, (err, data)=>{
      listData.push(data);
      if(listData.length === checkedList.length)doneFunc(listData);
      next();
    });
  }, err=>{
     console.log(err);
  });
}
whatever(listRes=>{
  console.log(listRes);
});
```

Comment: when i have an array of two or more items the function returns an error saying  `
Error: Callback was already called.`